# ScrollViewer scrollbar appears prematurely

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, scrollview

I have a GridView with three columns inside of a List view.

```
<ListView  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >                    
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Width="100" />               
        <GridViewColumn Width="130" />               
        <GridViewColumn Width="130" />           
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

When resizing the columns, the horizontal scrollbar appears before any of the content goes out of view. I only want it to appear if some of the content in the GridView is out of view.

Example photos:

Why does the first screenshot have a scrollbar? It only disappears if I resize the "Next Run" column to have that big margin on its right.

[image: Why does the scrollbar appear here]
----[image: but not appear here?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the reason why the scrollbar appears so soon, I was able to solve my problem with the following code that manually enables the horizontal scrollbar *only when the content is out of view*.

```
 <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

and fire this off in the constructor of the Window:

```
//If the sum of all column widths > ListView width -> enable scrollbar.
foreach (var column in gridView.Columns)
{
  ((INotifyPropertyChanged)column).PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
  {
    if (e.PropertyName == "ActualWidth")
    {
      var totalColumnWidth = gridView.Columns.Sum(col => col.ActualWidth);
      var listViewWidth = listView.ActualWidth;
      if (totalColumnWidth > listViewWidth)
        listView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);
      else
        listView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're fitting the listview inside a container which is exactly the same size as the total width of each row then it has no space left for the vertical scroll bar and the UI always reserves that space in WPF, it would overlap the content, that's why that last column is visible, to reserve that space

Comment: That makes total sense, but unfortunately disabling the vertical scrollbar doesn't seem to change anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't need vertical scrollbar, then why use a listview? why not using directly a gridview and add rows to it?

Comment: I do need a vertical scrollbar; I was just making the observation that disabling it didn't fix my problem :)

Comment: For what I saw that only happens on the WPF listview, on the WinForms listview if the vertical scrollbar is not present it doesn't requires that extra gap, so this may be a bug or a dessign decission to always reserve that space. Updated my answer.